# estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath best practice

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a UITableCell that displays dynamic content of various type.

There are labels that can be 1 or 2 lines, textViews with various heights, images with various heights.

What is the best way to estimate height for these rows? I can make functions that calculates height for labels and textviews. But for the constraints, can i make outlet and sum upp all the height constants?

Comment: Show tablecells that you have in your tableview. Applying proper constraints and setting estimatedRowHeight can make your cell grow automatically depending on content it have.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up your auto layout correctly. You don't have to calculate the constant yourself. You can simply set two properties (or do it in table view delegates):

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80;
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and OS will check the correct cell height for you.

If you have a few different cells the best way to make it works smooth is implement a delegate method instead of do it via property `tableView.estimatedRowHeight`, for example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // 1. get table view cell for indexPath
    // 2. check which cell type have you got
    // 3. return as closed estimated value for the cell type as you possible can.
    // Example
    //if cell type is my cell A return 80
    // else if cell is B return 120, etc

}
```

Comment: I have that, but i get a "jumpy/laggy" tableview so it's not working. I change a lot of constraint and height values in cellForRowAtIndexPath, maybe thats the reason?

Comment: Is your estimatedRowHeight value the approximately what your cell height should be? It must be close as much as you can specify. Try add it to delegate methods instead of tableView. properties.

Comment: I have 5 different type of cells in my TableView, all have different estimatedRowHeight, so how can i set one value for my whole TableView?

Comment: Hi @Greg. Can you please provide an example on `if cell type is my cell A return 80
    // else if cell is B return 120, etc`? I got 5 static cells however, I want to make one resizable (according to the textview inside). I'd be grateful

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can help

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] init];
height = [self calculateHeightForAttributeString:attrStr];
return height;
}




-(CGFloat)calculateHeightForAttributeString:(NSAttributedString *)attrStr {
 CGRect frame;
frame = [attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(labelMaxWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                          options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                          context:nil];
return frame.size.height;  
}
```